# libm.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: centos6, glibc, shared, ldd

I've install a program in Centos 6.8, While running the program, I receive error 
"error while loading shared libraries: libm.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
when I checked the linked library to the program using ldd command, I can see libm.so.6 with correct 64bit
"libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003a19000000)"
That means, library is installed and already added in environment variable, LD_LIBRARY_PATH
Another program, which uses libm.so.6, works fine.
Can anyone help to solve this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: Please show the `ldd` command you actually ran, and its output.

Answer (score 2):

In programming, *details* matter.

> Lets say, The program which I am trying to run is ABC and install

This is not details, this is a hypothetical. If you want *useful* answers, you should supply *actual* details that you are asked for. In particular, edit your question (instead of commenting on a different useless answer), and do this: "show the ldd command you actually ran, and its actual output."

That said, if `ldd /usr/local/ABC/bin/ABC` really does show `libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6`, then there is no way for `ABC` to *not* find `libm.so.6`.

Therefore we must conclude that `ABC` invokes some *other* program, and *that* program fails to find `libm.so.6`. You can confirm this guess by running:

```
LD_DEBUG=files,libs /usr/local/ABC/bin/ABC
```

This will show that `ABC` does find `libm.so.6`, what other program it invokes, and where that other program looks for `libm.so.6`.

It is likely that the other program is 32-bit, and looks for `/lib/libm.so.6`, and that you don't have 32-bit runtime libraries installed.

You can install them with `yum install glibc.i686` or some such.